# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory

Tags: apache-spark

I'm getting the above error message when I'm trying to run spark submit comment :

```
spark-submit --class "retail.DataValidator" --master local --executor-memory 2g --total-executor-cores 2 sample-spark-180417_2.11-1.0.jar /home/hduser/Downloads/inputfiles/  /home/hduser/output/
```

ERROR Message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/typesafe/config/ConfigFactory
at retail.DataValidator$.main(DataValidator.scala:12)
at retail.DataValidator.main(DataValidator.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 11 more
```

build.sbt file:

```
name := "sample-spark-180417"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.42"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.10+"
```

I'm not having any maven dependencies or pom.xml file.

Thanks

Comment: As per sbt file, you have added this: `libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"`. ------------------- That jar is mainly responsible for ClassDefNotFound exception.  -->>> Check if that jar gets discarded while building the jar.

Comment: I use "sbt package" command to build the jar from the path of the program.How to check whether it is added to jar, please advice

Comment: In case of fat-jar, Unzip your jar `sample-spark-***.jar` and see if it has folders like `com/typesafe/config/******`.

Comment: Otherwise,

Add this in spark-submit command: `--jars /fullpath/first.jar` to include the jar `"com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"`

Comment: i used this command to view the content of the jar file "jar tf jar-file" but type-safe its not there

Comment: So, Please try once the way mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: I tried as you said like, spark-submit --class "retail.DataValidator" --master local --executor-memory 2g --total-executor-cores 2 --jars /home/hduser/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.3.1.jar sample-spark-180417_2.11-1.0.jar /inputpath/ dev /outputpath/, but got this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Comment: Can you post full stacktrace!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it's not a fat jar, the spark cluster is not having typesafe jar in its classpath.

Submit the spark job as::

```
spark-submit --jars ./typesafe-***.jar --class "retail.DataValidator" --master local --executor-memory 2g --total-executor-cores 2 sample-spark-180417_2.11-1.0.jar /home/hduser/Downloads/inputfiles/  /home/hduser/output/
```

It will keep that jar in classpath, and submit the job.

Comment: Thank you its working fine now, could you please tell me this I used "--executor-memory 2g --total-executor-cores 2" but in localhost:4040 UI its showing me no of cores 1 and storage memory is 383.9 MB how to fix this